# Change order in .net resx file

Tags: .net, resx

Is there a way to change the order of keys in a resx file? I'm only using strings if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, a .resx file behaves like a dictionary.  Dictionaries are unordered collections, you find stuff back through the key value, the order is unimportant.  Technically you can, with a text editor.